# Google Code downloads discontinued: What to use instead?

Tags: upload, download, google-code

Google Code's [downloads](http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/downloads) feature allows project maintainers to upload binary files at no cost, either:

- using the web interface, or
- using an API, which is very convenient to integrate in build script.

**PROBLEM:** This downloads feature [will be retired on January 15, 2014](http://google-opensource.blogspot.jp/2013/05/a-change-to-google-code-download-service.html).
Is there an alternative?

Requirements:

- Upload file via API
- Anyone can download from direct URL, no delay nor advertisement/registration step

Preferably:

- Domain that inspire confidence in the Open Source community. For instance, a service at "gnu.org" would be better than a service at "warez.biz".
- Website usable by smartphone.

SourceForge and CodePlex have downloads, but hide them behind [delay/advertisement](http://sourceforge.net/projects/librecad/files/OSX/2.0.0alpha4/LibreCAD-2.0.0alpha4.dmg/download).
Bitbucket has no advertisements, but [no API to upload files](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3251/add-custom-file-uploads-to-rest-api-bb).

Comment: What about CodePlex? It seems to have a working API ( https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodePlexWebServices&referringTitle=CodePlexAPI ).

Comment: @Cesar: I had not thought of them, indeed! Feel free to propose as an answer. There does not seem to be a way to download without an advertisement step, though? For instance https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/downloads/get/621827

Comment: Perhaps it could be possible to get the raw link for the download, but not sure it will always work: http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=virtualrouter&DownloadId=621827&FileTime=130050070506570000&Build=20539

Comment: Questions seeking application recommendations are now considered off-topic for this site. See the [help/on-topic]. We have a sister site for application recommendations, but your question needs to meet [certain guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Check that your question meets the requirements, then you can repost your question on the [Software Recommendations site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Bintray.com](https://bintray.com) is a social platform for community-based software distribution. 
It is also the only platform that integrates developer tools (Build tools, etc.) and APIs, allowing full process automation, including auto-generating of indexes for multiple repository formats and also, the platform is highly available and optimized to deliver high-performance downloads (CDN).

BTW - I'm affiliated with JFrog, the creator of Bintray.

URLs look like `http://dl.bintray.com/username/projectname/filename`

Comment: What's your affiliation with this product?

Comment: The text is taken from Bintray website. (And Bintray is free)

Answer (score 1):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/publish/?source=googlecode) is doing its best to use this opportunity to rise from its ashes:

> SourceForge welcomes Google Code open source developers, to distribute downloads from our open source platform.
>   By distributing your releases at SourceForge you’ll get a complete download analytics, and the opportunity to tap into a large open source community. We already serve other ecosystems by offering their hosted projects our download facilities, including Githubbers.

SourceForge has a download API (actually rsync/ssh). Unfortunately, it has direct download links... you can construct links like [this](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmissync/CmisSync_1.0.10.msi) but SourceForge always manages to slip its ad-ridden page through.

---

Meanwhile, it [seems](http://developers.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=3779397&cid=43806569) that Google wants people to use [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) instead.

Unfortunately, Google Drive has several drawbacks:

- URLs like `https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-SI__O0UX9ob2JLRmNkeE41UEU` do not inspire trust. It could be anyone uploading any kind of virus.
- Many companies block Google Drive, because it is often used (like Dropbox and USB sticks) to circumvent company IT policies and [ECM](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) rules.
- It is not a direct link. HTTP GET was too standard I guess? Download stats will drop a bit, some users will not understand, and scripts will have to be rewritten (if integration is even possible).